# TypeError (expected numeric): app/models/order_item.rb:46:in `only_3_items_in_30_days'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm building a store in Rails that has a specific sales model. I need to allow a user to add only 3 items to his order per 30 days. The 30 days counter should start upon adding the first order_item. Once 30 days expires, user would be able to add 3 orders. If 30 days didn't pass and for an example, user adds two order_items he would still be allowed to add one more order_item within 30 days. So as well if user tries to add more then 3 items to show an error message and disregard saving of the order_items to current_user's order.

I'm getting this error in my log right now in my logs:

```
TypeError (expected numeric):
  app/models/order_item.rb:46:in `only_3_items_in_30_days'
```

controller:

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
 def create
     @item = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)
  session[:order_id] = current_order.id

  if @item.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end 
end
end


  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end



  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end


private

  def order_item_params
  base_params = params.require(:order_item)
                      .permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id)
  base_params.merge(order: current_order)
 end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present
validate :only_3_items_in_30_days

  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end



  def only_3_items_in_30_days
    now = Date.new
    days_since_first = now - order.first_item_added_at

    if order.order_items.count > 2 && days_since_first < 30
      errors.add(:base, 'only 3 items in 30 days are allowed')
    end
    true      # this is to make sure the validation chain is not broken in case the check fails
  end



end
```

Comment: As a person with no ruby experience, is it possible that subtracting two dates doesn't give a number of days, but some kind of time span object?

Comment: try `Date.today`..? Also did you actually `require 'date'`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is two-fold.

First you want to use `DateTime.current` for line 45 (which is the proper way to talk about "now"`

Secondly the error is actually saying that you can't subtract a date and `nil`.  So you need to nil check everything first.

```
def only_3_items_in_30_days
  unless order.first_item_added_at
    return true #(or whatever you want to do in this case)
  end

  now = Time.current
  days_since_first = now - order.first_item_added_at
  ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by "Date object?" I need to specify it somewhere that it is a date object?

Comment: To do the subtraction operation on dates both need to be of object type Date (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) , I assume from the error message that the latter is just a string.

Comment: It is a string, how can edit first_item_added_at to datetime field?

Comment: Already modified my answer.  `days_since_first = now - Date.parse(order.first_item_added_at)`

Comment: Now I get this error: TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  app/models/order_item.rb:46:in `parse'
  app/models/order_item.rb:46:in `only_3_items_in_30_days'
  app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:6:in `create'

Comment: It is datetime field

Comment: Now you need to add a check to see if it's `nil` as the error message says.  So first check `if order.first_item_added_at` before doing anything since your model allows for a nil value.

Comment: Would you please tell how to check?

Comment: I would use `Time.current` here, rather than `DateTime`.

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting a new error by action view but don't know which one: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <% if @order.errors.any? || @order_item.errors.any? %>
    2: alert("not valid.")
    3: <% else %>
    4:   $(".cart-text").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text') %>")
  app/views/order_items/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_order_items_create_js_erb___4497417446440553056_69945778367420'

Comment: That is unrelated to the issue in this thread.  Please accept the answer, and try debugging the issue yourself.  You will never learn how to code if you don't try to tackle these kind of issues yourself.